# docker-compose rails mysql connection refused

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, containers

I face an issue while trying to make docker-compose contains Rails API and MySQL and others.
After docker-compose up and send a request to the Rails API I get this error
`"#<Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'database' (111 \"Connection refused\")>"`

My docker-compose

```
services:
  database:
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - 'db_data:/var/lib/mysql'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root

  app:
    build: .
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - 'database'
      - 'redis'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - 'gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems'
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PORT'] || '5432' %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME_DEV'] %>
...
```

.env

```
...
DATABASE_HOST=database
...
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL uses 3306 as the default port, and you should assign 3306 to the `DATABASE_PORT` environment.

Comment: Now I got this error 
```Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.22.0.4' (using password: NO)>```

Comment: Assign `root` to `DATABASE_PASSWORD` as well ?